# Is the DSL version available to non-admin users

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

Obviously the installed version of the DSL version is available to admin users who can list plugins.  I’m also presuming that users with access to the script console can access it somehow.

But, is there a way for users who can, for example see/run/create jobs to dump the current DSL version?  I’d like to test my DSL scripts off the Jenkins host and having a like-for-like version would be helpful.